# How can I start a public openttd server?

Tags: openttd

Since now I press the Add Server to be able to play on our private server. But how is it possible to be able to see it when press Find Server from the beginning? How is it possible to register it on a public server list?

Wiki says: If you want your server to be visible on the public server list as well (recommended), you will also need to open port 3978 to UDP connections only.

And I have done so far following settings:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

if you want to make your server visible in public openttd server list, you need to:
1) set "server_advertise = true" and "lan_internet = 0" in your openttd.cfg
2) configure your firewall to allow both TCP and UDP inbound and outbound connections on port 3979, inbound UDP connections on 3978 and also outbound UDP connection on port 3978 to master.openttd.org

Of course, you need to have a public IP address assigned from your ISP - your screenshot only shows local LAN reserved IP 192.168.0.0/16.

Hope this helps you :).